# Отправка файла через форму размером более 34 Мб

Tags: php

Есть форма которая работает и отправляет файлы, но когда я пытаюсь отправить файл более 34 Мб, то выдается ошибка

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate Y bytes)

Повышение директивы memory_limit до 256 не помогло!

Ошибка ссылается на строку

```
$encoded_content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content))
```

которая переводит файл в код по типу

```
OEJQUwABAAAAAAAAAAMAABdiAAAGKAAIAAMAAAAAAAFhWDhCSU0EBAAAAAABVxwBWgADGyVHHAFa
AAMbJUccAVoAAxslRxwBWgADGyVHHAFaAAMbJUccAVoAAxslRxwBWgADGyVHHAFaAAMbJUccAVoA
```

ну и соответственно в таком виде файл больше 128 Мб.
Если кто-то знает как преобразовывать файл по другому, подскажите пожалуйста!

В дальнейшем `$encoded_content` будет отправлен на почту

```
$body .= "--$boundary\r\n";
$body .="Content-Type: $file_type; name=".$file_name."\r\n";
$body .="Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$file_name."\r\n";
$body .="Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
$body .="X-Attachment-Id: ".rand(1000,99999)."\r\n\r\n";
$body .= $encoded_content;
```

Comment: в php.ini увеличивай memory_limit

Comment: Ух какой ты внимательный ! Вопрос перечитай !

Comment: Если по коду , то 
              ` $body .= "--$boundary\r\n";
                $body .="Content-Type: $file_type; name=".$file_name."\r\n";
                $body .="Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$file_name."\r\n";
                $body .="Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
                $body .="X-Attachment-Id: ".rand(1000,99999)."\r\n\r\n";
                $body .= $encoded_content;` 
и т.д.
А если по смыслу , то отправляю на почту в gmail !

Comment: @Олег а если `memory_limit -1` сделать?

Comment: Manitikyl , честно не уверен можно ли так сделать. сайт то находится на хостинге с конкретным значением директивы 128 Мб

Comment: Закодировать не проблема. Проблема отправить. Нужна возможность отправки частями. Кроме использования сокетов ничего в голову не приходит

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/filters.convert.php ща примерчик набросаю

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно кодировать и отправлять файл блоками.

Вот, как вариант (код отправки письма взят [отсюда](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mail.php#121858))

```php
function xxmail($to, $subject, $body, $headers) {
  $smtp = stream_socket_client('tcp://smtp.yourmail.com:25', $eno, $estr, 30);

  $B = 8192;
  $c = "\r\n";
  $s = 'myapp@someserver.com';

  fwrite($smtp, 'helo '.$_ENV['HOSTNAME'].$c);
  $junk = fgets($smtp, $B);

  // Envelope
  fwrite($smtp, 'mail from: '.$s.$c);
  $junk = fgets($smtp, $B);
  fwrite($smtp, 'rcpt to: '.$to.$c);
  $junk = fgets($smtp, $B);
  fwrite($smtp, 'data'.$c);
  $junk = fgets($smtp, $B);

  // Header 
  fwrite($smtp, 'To: '.$to.$c);
  if (strlen($subject)) fwrite($smtp, 'Subject: '.$subject.$c);
  if (strlen($headers)) fwrite($smtp, $headers); // Must be \r\n (delimited)
  fwrite($smtp, $headers.$c);

  // Body
  if (strlen($body)) fwrite($smtp, $body.$c);
  send_file($smtp);
  fwrite($smtp, $c . '.' . $c);
  $junk = fgets($smtp, $B);

  // Close
  fwrite($smtp, 'quit'.$c);
  $junk = fgets($smtp, $B);
  fclose($smtp);
}

function send_file($smtp, $lineLen = 76) {
  $file = fopen($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], 'rb');
  if (!$file)
    return;
  $lineLen = ($lineLen | 3) - 3;  // $lineLen должно быть кратно 4
  $bytes = $lineLen / 4 * 3;  // При кодировании в base64 из каждых 3 байт получаются 4
  $buflen = floor(4096 / $bytes) * $bytes; // Читаем файл блоками порядка 4кб, кратным длине строки
  while (!feof($file)) {
    $data = fread($file, $buflen);  // читаем блок данных
    $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));  // кодируем его
    fwrite($smtp, $data);  // Отправили в сокет
  }
  fclose($file);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вариант с использованием потоков. Данные кодируются и записываются в файл. Можно и не в файл. @see [Преобразовывающие фильтры](http://php.net/manual/ru/filters.convert.php)

```
<?php
// Ставим лимит памяти 1 Мб
ini_set('memory_limit', 1*1024*1024);
echo ini_get('memory_limit') . PHP_EOL;

// Большие данные
$content = 'My long long file';
$content = str_repeat($content, 50000);

// Эта строчка выдает ошибку "Fatal error: Allowed memory size ..." - как у ТС
// $encoded_content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));

// Создаем временный файл
$encoded_content_file = tempnam('/tmp/', 'enc_');

$fp = fopen($encoded_content_file, 'w');

// Фильтр для потока
$param = array('line-length' => 76, 'line-break-chars' => "\r\n");
stream_filter_append($fp, 'convert.base64-encode', STREAM_FILTER_WRITE, $param);

// Эта строка также вызывает переполнение памяти, поэтому разбиваем на порции и пишем
// fwrite($fp, $content);
$chunk = 1024;
for($i = 0; $i <= strlen($content); $i += $chunk) {
  fwrite($fp, substr($content, $i, $chunk));
}

fclose($fp);

// Выводим название временного файла
echo $encoded_content_file . PHP_EOL;
```